# jaxb and inheritance of an abstract class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i have the following hierarchy of Objects which i need to unmarshall from an XML:

```
A:
    String id;
    List<B>
B:
    String id;
    List<C>
C:
    String id;
```

i need to unmarshall them using JAXB to an xml that will look something like this (the objects are wrapped in a general O object):

```
<O>
<A id="someId">
    <B id="someId2">
      <C id="someId3">
    </B>
    <B id="someId4">
        <C id="someId5"/>
        <C id="someId6"/>
    </B>
</A>
</O>
```

Ive trying to do this by creating an object of type "GeneralType":

```
@XmlTransient
public abstract GeneralType:
    protected String id
    protected List<? extends GeneralType> myList

public O:
    List<A> aList;
    getter to aList with (@xmlElement(name="A"))

@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public A extends GeneralType:
    getId with @XmlAttribute(name="id")  
    getMyListwith @XmlAttribute(name="B")  

@XmlRootElement(name="B")
public B extends GeneralType:
    getId with @XmlAttribute(name="id")  
    getMyListwith @XmlAttribute(name="C")  

@XmlRootElement(name="C")
public C extends GeneralType:
    getId with @XmlAttribute(name="id")
```

Im getting an error:

```
@XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML.:
  A.getMyList
  O.getALit
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `@XmlAttribute` for `myList`? Try `@XmlElement`. You (normally) don't map complex class to an attribute.

Comment: Post real code and error messages referring to lines in that code. There is no good reason for C being a subclass of General Type. And if you inherit from GeneralType, fields like id and myList are defined by this base class, including the annotations that define the tag names etc. to be used by JAXB.